iOS Push to Talk Framework Not Working in Archive Build (Flutter)
I have developed an app using Flutter that utilizes the Push to Talk framework on iOS. The Push to Talk feature works perfectly in debug mode, but after archiving the build and installing it on an iOS 17 device, the Push to Talk functionality stops working.
Here are the steps I have already taken:

Enabled background modes.
Enabled Push to Talk capabilities.

Despite these settings, the issue persists in the archive build.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? What additional steps or configurations are required to get Push to Talk working in the archive build on iOS 17?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I tried:
Enabled Background Modes: I made sure that the Background Modes capability is enabled in the project settings, specifically for "Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture" and "Push to Talk."
Enabled Push to Talk Capabilities: I confirmed that the Push to Talk capability is correctly set up in the project's capabilities section.
Debug Mode Testing: I ran the app in debug mode, where the Push to Talk functionality works as expected.
What I was expecting:
I expected the Push to Talk functionality to work similarly in both debug and archive builds. Specifically, I expected that after archiving and installing the app on a device running iOS 17, the Push to Talk feature would function without issues.
Despite following the above steps, the Push to Talk functionality does not work in the archive build, although it works perfectly in debug mode.
